# Passing variable to included file in a method

Tags: php

I could not find the answer to this problem. I have a class written in PHP. Files included within a PHP class method do not seem inherit variables within the method scope.

```
class Classname {
    public function template_editor (){
        $GLOBALS['template_editor'] = true; 
        $editable=false;
        $GLOBALS['editing'] = false;
        $template_html =  $this->thetemplate (array('editable'=>$editable));
        include (TEMPLATE_DIR_URI."/inc/template_editor.php");
    }
}
```

I want the variable $template_html to be passed to the included file so that I can echo it. I have written many functions and all the variables declared in the functions are passed on to the included files but it does not work in class methods.

In the included file I currently have;

```
<?php echo  $template_html;  ?>
```

...and some html and Jquery. I want all the method variables to be availble in the included file so that I can use them in the included file.

Comment: I don't get it. The solution is right there in your code, twice. Why not use it for `$template_html`?

Comment: $template_html will be available in `TEMPLATE_DIR_URI."/inc/template_editor.php"` - are you sure it's getting set here? That included file should also be able to access $this->thetemplate() and any other methods - even with protected access - I have a working site that uses this. when using include, php includes the code as if it were inline right there in the file.

Comment: Where is it? I find it very strange. When I try to echo the variable $template_html in the included file template_editor.php no output is made. I can echo the variable fine within the method but not within the file.

Comment: Do you have any conditional (if/else) logic around where you echo $template_html?

Comment: No, I don't conditional statements just;

<?php echo  $template_html;  ?>

So the code that I have should definately work? PHP should make these variables available in the included file?

Comment: I have found the problem. I have been using the wrong constant: TEMPLATE_DIR_URI which is an http url rather than a server directory string.

Problem fixed. Thanks.

Comment: I have a lot of things going on so I could not sense it. I am in a wordpress environment with a bootstrap theme so lots of files are being called before this one file is included. The constant TEMPLATE_DIR_URI is declared very far. So I thought it was a variable scope problem.

Problem solved. You've helped. I have had this problem for days wondering what is wrong until I have echoed TEMPLATE_DIR_URI

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation of include()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php):

> If the include occurs inside a function within the calling file, then
>   all of the code contained in the called file will behave as though it
>   had been defined inside that function. So, it will follow the variable
>   scope of that function. An exception to this rule are magic constants
>   which are evaluated by the parser before the include occurs.

Your problem is most likely that either this line isn't assigning a value to `$template_html`

```
$template_html =  $this->thetemplate (array('editable'=>$editable));
```

or you are referencing the variable incorrectly in template_editor.php.

Checking the value of `$template_html` like so may give you insight into the reason:

```
class Classname {
    public function template_editor (){
        $GLOBALS['template_editor'] = true; 
        $editable=false;
        $GLOBALS['editing'] = false;
        $template_html =  $this->thetemplate (array('editable'=>$editable));

        // Add this for debugging
        if (is_empty($template_html)) {
            error_log('$template_html is empty.');
        }

        include (TEMPLATE_DIR_URI."/inc/template_editor.php");
    }
}
```

Comment: I can echo $template_html with the method but not within the included file.

Comment: Could you update your question to include the relevant section from the included file where you echo the variable?